# Regular expression for tokenizing an argument list (VBScript)

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm trying to create a regular expression that will tokenize a string of the following format:
Program.EXE someparam:[[REG|HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows]]  someotherparam[[DATA|User]] couldbeanotherparam

The regular expression I'm looking for is to get all [[REG|any text]] OR [[DATA|any text]] occurrences in my string.

My main problem is to treat each instance as a separate token. 
When trying something like [[REG\|.+]] it the first occurrence of [[ and the last occurrence of ]] as the expression boundaries. I suppose it has to do with the .+.

The result I'm looking for in the example above is:
[[REG|HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows]]
[[DATA|User]]

Answer (score 0):

Repeaters are greedy by default:

```
[[(REG|DATA)\|.+?]]
```

Adding the question mark makes it as ungreedy as possible so it will stop at the first instance of "]]" it can find.

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks a lot. Works like a charm. Just spent on that @#$% 2 hours!